# Better workflow for Weight Painting?

Tags: workflow, weight-painting

I paint weights by going back and forth between the add and subtract brushes on the toolbar, but it is time consuming and kind of silly in terms of workflow. I noticed weight painting doesn't have an option to subtract by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> like sculpt mode does. Is there something I am missing?